# Something strange

Tags: switch, light

Ultimate light switches would be off in the down position. All of a sudden one has changed where the on position is off and the off position is on. There's no second switch and this just happened at the sky blue. What would do this? No pranksters in the house.**strong text**

Comment: Someone can take out the switch and install it upside down.

Comment: Based on your own answer to your question, a garage light is very often controlled by a 3-way switch arrangement, with switches at all entry points to the garage. Look around for other switches in the garage that turn the garage light on or off. Once you find another one that turns the light on, you can turn the regular switch off normally.

Comment: If the switch changed, it is in the 0.01% of the way they break.  The only repair is replacing the switch with the breaker off.

Comment: BTW, I didn't downvote, but you should proofread your questions and edit things as needed. The bolded "Strong Text" isn't a defining part of the question's information. Use the "Edit" below the question link to edit mitakes.

Comment: Please reread your first sentence from our perspective. What does "Ultimate light switches..." mean?

Answer (score 2):

Regular light switches simply do **NOT** work that way. The possibilities are:

- Three-way switch - i.e., at least two separate switches, where each one can turn the light on/off. One of those can be hidden behind a cabinet, furniture, refrigerator, etc. and forgotten. Or even be out in the open but normally ignored. Then someone either deliberately or accidentally flips a switch and now the usual switch is effectively reversed.
- Prankster turned the switch. Unlikely in most houses.

A switch can:

- Be stuck in "on" mode
- Be stuck in "off" mode

But there is really no way for it be reversed.

There is a trick on traditional toggle switches (as opposed to the flat "Decora" switches) to see if it is a 3-way switch or not. If it is a regular, not 3-way, switch then you will see "ON" and "OFF" marked on the switch itself. Here is an "OFF" from [a Leviton switch at Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Single-Pole-Toggle-Light-Switch-White-R52-01451-02W/100026991):

[image: switch - off]

and here is an "ON":

[image: switch - on]

If it doesn't have ON/OFF markings then it is very likely a 3-way switch, and you just have to keep searching until you find the other one.

If it is a "Decora" style switch then the only way to tell for sure is to open up the switchbox to see how many wires are connected. A regular switch will normally have two screws for wires (plus ground, which may or may not be connected for various reasons). A 3-way switch will have three screws for wires and a 4-way switch (middle switches between 3-way switches at each end) will have four wires.